# Fulltext index in MySQL for mediumtext field?

Tags: mysql, indexing, freetext

Is it at all possible to add a working fulltext index on a mediumtext field in oracle? I have been able to make an index, but I do not get any results when I query it. It might be that my sql is flawed: (ps. I am absolutely sure that the 'someText' part is in the DB).

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE CONTAINS (ProductDescription, 'someText' );
```

I also tried with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE CONTAINS (ProductDescription, 'someText' )>0;
```

But no results.

The strange thing is that the query returns no error, it simply does not return results. It might be that my index is inproperly created, but in "phpMyAdmin" it is listed as one of the indexes for my table. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't sound like Oracle when you say phpMyAdmin, fulltext and mediumtext - sounds more like a MySQL database?

Comment: Yeah, accually it might be:p My bad. A help-link in phpMyAdmin directed me to a oracle site, so I was not sure. Probably because they bought sun.

Answer (score 0):

How have you built your index ?

Specifically, are you syncing the index changes to the table changes [ON COMMIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/text.101/b10730/csql.htm#i1000959)

Comment: I do believe that the index is buldt. I am not, however, syncing t. Do you have an example of how to add the sync after the index is made? (the index is quite big, so I dont want to have to create it all over again).